# Most efficient way to search array of object values

Tags: javascript

I have an onChange function that is called each time a user enters something into a text field. The idea is to autocomplete or provide a list of options that contain the text the user has entered, and let them choose from the returned options. Here is what I have:

```
dataSet.filter(option => option.label.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
```

dataSet would look something like this, and could have thousands of elements:

```
[
  {
    label: "I'm typing this",
    value: "1234567890"
  },
]
```

What would be a better, more efficient approach, without getting too crazy?

Comment: you can `toLowerCase()` at least one of the values before the loop to avoid redundant work. you can also use `"".includes()` instead of `"".indexOf()`, or a RegExp `RegExp(input,"i")` so that you can `.test()` for things without explicitly converting to lowercase.

Comment: Your code would only make sure that your label contains your input, not that it's a complete match. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to match on the label. I suppose I should have explicitly stated that,  but assumed the code told the story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [debounce as explained in this post](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) for that.

> // Returns a function, that, as long as it continues to be invoked,
>   will not
>        be triggered. The function will be called after it stops being called for
>        N milliseconds. If `immediate` is passed, trigger the function on the
>        leading edge, instead of the trailing.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

You can benefit from it like- Instead of calling `onChange`on every keystroke it will call only after a certain milliseconds have passed which you can set in the debounce function.

And you can use it like

```
var myEfficientFn = debounce(onChange, 400);
```

So if the user have stopped typing for 400ms than only it will call the `onChange` function instead of in every keystroke.